Keil C51: Dead Loop in Custom Delay Function (STC89C52RC)
I'm trying to write a simple delay function. It takes two arguments: a pointer to a void function and an unsigned integer (unsigned int) specifying how many times the function should be executed. However, I'm encountering a dead loop, preventing the code after the function call from executing.
void delay(void (*func)(void), unsigned int time) {
    unsigned int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < time; i++) {
        func();
        for (j = 0; j < 10000; j++);
    }
}

In an attempt to avoid using functions, I implemented the following code:
void main() {
    unsigned int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < time; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10000; j++);
        func();
    }
    // other codes to be executed
}

I was surprised to find that this code avoids the dead loop I encountered previously. I'm confused about this. Maybe it has something to do with the function pointer? (The complier is Keil C51)

for (j = 0; j < 10000; j++); is a no-op, the compiler is free to remove that whole useless loop. For dirty delays like this, you need to declare the iterator as volatile. A better idea is to write proper code and use the on-chip hardware timers instead.

You may need to clarify what you mean by "dead loop".

What does func point to in the first example.  Why is func() called in the innermost loop in the second example, but not the first. They are not comparable.

Use your debugger, verify func refers to the function you intended.  Without seeing the calling code we cannot determine whether that is an issue, and without seeing the function itself, we cannot determine what it might do.  Would be wise at least to test for NULL before calling it.  The innermost loop being empty, may be optimised away.  https://beta.embedded.com/introduction-to-the-volatile-keyword

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then please come back and [edit] your question to extend the shown code to [mre], both of them. Oh, and add what you mean by "dead loop".

Keil supports the __nop() function that does nothing but isn't optimized out by the compiler. So you might write a delay function like this:
void delay(unsigned int time)
{
    while(time--)
    {
        __nop();
    }
}

If for some reason your compiler doesn't have __nop(), you can also do the following to generate a proper NOP in Keil C51.
#pragma asm
    NOP
#pragma endasm

Of course it would be better to use a hardware timer to get a precise delay. But if you just want "some" dealy the above should be fine.
